# Place (fixed) dropdown menus with javascript to avoid z-index inheritance issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project that includes pages to view and select actions on multiple different entities of the same category set. Those entities are presented in the form of cards (e.g. employees, projects etc). On each card there is a classic gear button that expands a hidden drop menu so that the user can select actions (which might be the same or different for each entity/card). In order to avoid z-index inheritance issues (e.g. drop menu appearing on top of the parent but behind the sibling card) I implemented the solution presented in the link below (minimal representation).

The solution seems to be working fine, but i am wondering if it is elegant / acceptable in the context of implementing it on a production environment. If someone could comment on it or propose other solutions if this is not "acceptable" that would be great.

```js
function getFixedElementPosition(el, menuid) {
  var dropmenu = document.getElementById(`dropmenu${menuid}`);
  if (dropmenu.style.display === "" || dropmenu.style.display === "none") {
    var pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    dropmenu.style.top = `${pos.bottom}px`;
    dropmenu.style.left = `${pos.right}px`;
    dropmenu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dropmenu.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
.card {
  width: 225px;
  height: 295px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(38, 57, 77) 0px 2px 30px -10px;
}

.gear {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.dropmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a:hover {
  color: #003a95;
}

p {
  margin: 35px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="gear" onclick="getFixedElementPosition(this, 1)" src="https://www.indivstock.com/static35/preview2/stock-vector-gear-icon-illustrated-in-vector-on-white-background-520258.jpg" width="34">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
  </div>
  <!--  /Card #1  -->

  <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenu" onmouseleave="this.style.display='none';">
    <a href="#!">View</a>
    <a href="#!">Edit</a>
    <a href="#!">Delete</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="gear" onclick="getFixedElementPosition(this, 2)" src="https://www.indivstock.com/static35/preview2/stock-vector-gear-icon-illustrated-in-vector-on-white-background-520258.jpg" width="34">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
  </div>
  <!--  /Card #2  -->

  <div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenu" onmouseleave="this.style.display='none';">
    <a href="#!">View</a>
    <a href="#!">Edit</a>
    <a href="#!">Delete</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="gear" onclick="getFixedElementPosition(this, 3)" src="https://www.indivstock.com/static35/preview2/stock-vector-gear-icon-illustrated-in-vector-on-white-background-520258.jpg" width="34">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
  </div>
  <!--  /Card #3  -->

  <div id="dropmenu3" class="dropmenu" onmouseleave="this.style.display='none';">
    <a href="#!">View</a>
    <a href="#!">Edit</a>
    <a href="#!">Delete</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/t3l3machus/pen/GRvbjzM

P.S. The numbered ids (dropmenu1, dropmenu2..) are created by a template engine on document load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could change and also some bugs.

The dropdown only works once because you're setting `display = "none"` but comparing it with empty string.

You can wrap this on a `<div>` that has `position:absolute` and then use `position:relative` to position the dropdown relative to the wrapper. This way you only have to set the display value.

Check out my updated version:
https://codepen.io/samura_lesi/pen/MWvMpKX

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Your solution is useful in order to improve mine, but it doesn't work properly when the card has content. I am currently updating my codepen to include content if you want check it out again

Comment: you just need to put the `<p>` outside the gear-wrapper. I updated my solution